# How can I display stacked barcharts horizontally in Flot?

Tags: jquery, flot, bar-chart

I see how to display barcharts in flot with horizontal bars,  or vertical bars, which can be "stacked" vertically,  but I can't find examples of how to display barcharts that are horizontal AND stacked.

How would I do this?

Here's the code I have,  copied from the poster below's site,  but still the bars won't stack

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {


var d1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
    d1.push([parseInt(Math.random() * 30),i]);


var d2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
    d2.push([parseInt(Math.random() * 30),i]);

var d3 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
    d3.push([parseInt(Math.random() * 30),i]);

$.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, d3 ], { series: {
            stack: true,
            lines: { show:false },
            bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.6, horizontal:true } }  });

});

</script>

<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just specify both `stack:true` and in your bars definition `horizontal:true`, that should be it...

```
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
        series: {
            stack: true,
            lines: { show:false },
            bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.6, horizontal:true }
        }
    });
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/wt6aJ/

Comment: Ryley thank you very much,  I have tried copying your code and it I still am not getting stacking bars.    Pasted code above.

Comment: you may have to get the newest version of flot from their code repository, you'll notice in the jsfiddle that I am using files from here: http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk

Comment: ah you're right.  i upgraded to flot 0.7 and now they stack horizontally.   thanks!